# How to find a representation of general linear group with the following property.

Tags: representation-theory, general-linear-group

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. Let $W$ be a representation of $GL\left( V \right)$ with a homomorphism $f:S^2W\rightarrow \bigwedge ^n V$ as $GL\left( V \right)$ representations, what is $W$ and $f$?

If $n$ is a multiple of 4, $n=4k$, it seems that $W=\bigwedge^{2k} V$ seems to work, i.e. $f:S^2\bigwedge^{2k} V\rightarrow \bigwedge^{4k} V$ where $f:xy\mapsto x\land y$. Are there other solutions? Are there solutions with $n\neq 4k$?

If $S^2W$ decomposes into irreducible subreprentations, then it seems we should have $S^2W\cong \bigwedge ^n V \oplus \ker f$, but I'm not sure where to go from here. It seems that finding solutions should have something to do with plethysm and Schur Weyl duality, but I'm not clear about these things right now.

Comment: "what is $W$ and $f$?" sounds like bad question formulation. Did you mean to say, can you find nontrivial examples of $W$ and $f$ such that...